# Hawk auth works with python Requests but not JS Axios

Tags: javascript, python, django-rest-framework, python-requests, axios

I have a server that uses Hawk authentication (Django Rest Framework).

When making authenticated requests, I have no trouble with the python `requests` package.

However, when using the javascript `axios` package, the `Authorization` header doesn't reach my authentication middleware.

**Python request with `requests`, works**

```
->
GET /logout/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Accept-Encoding: identity
Authorization: Hawk mac="sPJZet9eQKyBZSBpbGVQefPzsfBIXNFJDWAPF93n6fA=", hash="q/t+NNAkQZNlq/aAD6PlexImwQTxwgT2MahfTa9XRLA=", id="z1dkOdDr", ts="1528778355", nonce="gBZQRS"

<-
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2018 04:39:15 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.4
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Server-Authorization: Hawk mac="jBlHlyWCkirfBafbfw+N4iadwuQEsX99pATGXqxjOCY=", hash="2BRBGFjKOpKo9GffbS9rYZddAd5xoq/WdfD0Fm9wDhk="
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 41
{"detail": "user secret has been changed"}
```

**JS request with `axios`, fails because the auth middleware does not see `Authorization` in the headers:**

```
->
GET /logout/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Hawk id="7RdDRgkJ", ts="1528778122", nonce="TQWhoS", mac="nrX3bJbVF1wQt/tWrmUf/y/oEmAE6oFPyM5uP5sqzLg="
User-Agent: axios/0.18.0
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: close

<-
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2018 04:35:22 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.4
Content-Type: application/json
WWW-Authenticate: Hawk
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 39
{"detail": "Hawk authentication failed"}
```

The differences seem nominal.  What could be creating the issue? The `Authorization` header is definitely be stripped before it the request reaches the authentication middleware, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: For me it was happening due to a misconfig in apache

Comment: Why would the Authorization header make it through in one case and not the other?  The problem also occurs with the development server, so the removal of the header must be occurring in Django's request middleware somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that Axios does not re-attach the `Authorization` header after a 301 redirect response - i.e., there was no `Authorization` header on the actual `GET` request to the correct (backslash-appended) url.  The solution was to separate the requests and ensure the header's presence - or just get the endpoint url correct the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue, where subsequent requests beyond the login request was being treated as a different session by the server. I had searched all over the place to find what to do, before I happened to run over request package's built-in cookie option, https://www.npmjs.com/package/request .

Cookies are disabled by default in request (else, they would be used in subsequent requests). To enable cookies, set jar to true (either in defaults or options).

```
var request = request.defaults({jar: true})
request('http://www.google.com', function () {
  request('http://images.google.com')
})
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the popular axios, you need to get some more javascript packages. I landed on this solution, https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cookiejar-support . It seems like despite all the cool stuff that axios can do in terms of promises, it doesn't come with built-in support for cookies unless you include some other packages.

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
const axiosCookieJarSupport = require('@3846masa/axios-cookiejar-support').default;
// const axiosCookieJarSupport = require('axios-cookiejar-support').default;
const tough = require('tough-cookie');

axiosCookieJarSupport(axios);

const cookieJar = new tough.CookieJar();

axios.get('https://google.com', {
  jar: cookieJar, // tough.CookieJar or boolean
  withCredentials: true // If true, send cookie stored in jar
})
.then(() => {
  console.log(cookieJar);
});
```

I hope this helps someone out there, it took me a full day to figure out what was wrong with my request.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)